# In a Batch File: How to echo each variable assigned from lines in a text file that are in a For loop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file that reads each line in a text file and assigns it (each line) to a variable.

I am using the example found here: [Read each line in a txt file and assign variables using windows dos commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091656/read-each-line-in-a-txt-file-and-assign-variables-using-windows-dos-commands), which is:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%x IN ("%TEXT_T%") DO (
SET var!count!=%%x
SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Now, all I want to do is echo the results of each variable, but I just can't seem to be able to do so. Below is what I have, which gives me the results for var0 three times--my text file has three lines. I changed the start of count from the above code from 1 to 0.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET count=0
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%x IN ("afile.txt") DO (
SET var!count!=%%x
echo !var%count%!
SET /a count=!count!+1
echo !count!
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: The problem is that `%count%` is not using delayed expansion and so isn't being incremented.  Explain what you need to do because there are different solutions depending on what task is being performed.

Comment: I just want to show the results of the file. That's it. Then I will do something like start "" notepad.exe var1 var2 var3, but without me specifying the number after var.

Comment: Add the command `set var` after the loop, which will display them.  There's a different technique to concatenate a list of items into one string.

Comment: I am not understanding. What's the correct way to write the `%count%` part so that I can see the result of the text file being echoed each time?

Answer (score 2):

While this code

```
echo !var%count%!
```

seems logic, as `count` is changed inside the loop, you can not access the value of the variable without delayed expansion. But

```
      echo !var!count!!
           ^...^     ^^
first variable        second "variable"
```

will not work, as the parser is not able to properly determine where each variable reference start/end

You can use any of the two following lines

```
for %%a in (!count!) do echo !var%%a!

call echo %%var!count!%%
```

**How does it work?**

The original idea is good, but there are limits in the syntax. We need delayed expansion over the `var..` variable, but also over the `count`.

**1.-** In the first solution, we store the delayed expansion of the `count` variable inside the `for` replaceable parameter, that is used instead of the `count` variable in the `echo` command, keeping the delayed expansion only around the `var` variable.

```
!var!count!!   =>    %%a=!count!   =>   !var%%a!
```

**2.-** In the second solution, a `call` command is used. This call causes a double evaluation of the line, first on the line parse to execute the `call`, second while call execution. That is, the line

```
call echo %%var!count!%%
```

is first parsed, and the only variable referenced in it is `!count!` (a double percent sign is a single escaped percent sign), so the line is translated into (suppose `count` contains `5`)

```
call echo %var5%
```

Now, the call is executed, line is parsed again to execute the echo and the value of the correct variable is retrieved.

Comment: **Thank you!!!** This was driving me crazy. `!var!count!!` seemed to be the logical solution, but it's not. And everywhere I looked online, people would manually specify the echoing of the variables: i.e. var1, var2, and so on. I chose the 2nd one because it requires me changing the least amount of code. Plus, I am simply mimicking the above code and working with the areas I understand. **1. Can you please explain what's the purpose of the double percentages (%%)? 2. Also, for your 1st solution, where would I specify the filename?**

Comment: @rolo, i've included more details in the answer. Hope it helps. For the seconds question, there is no file name. The `for` i have included retrieves the value from inside the variable, not any file

Comment: Thanks again. I will have to re-read this a few times to be sure I fully understand it. Maybe you can help me with my other question, which is a continuation of this one: [Batch Files: How to concatenate each line in a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751630/batch-files-how-to-concatenate-each-line-in-a-text-file)